# How to set a different child size to dojo accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I'm using dojo for a project, and i have some pages where i use dijit/layout/AccordionContainer, this accordions have 3 child containers or more , usually those containers are changing their height dynamically depending by the avalible height on the current page. I have to say that the accordion was generated using declarative example from the dojo docs.

But sometimes i need only one Accordion container to be bigger than the rest.

[image]

For example: i need the last container( named: this too) to be bigger that the others two...

My implementation is simple, i used the docs example:

```
<div class="hook" style="width: 300px;">
<div class="hook" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Heeh, this is a content pane">
        Hi!
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="This is as well" selected="true">
        Hi how are you?
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="This too">
        Hi how are you? .....Great, thx
    </div>
</div>
```

Then using the class hook i just add the page available height, and dojo makes all the containers equal.

Tnx!

Comment: Is this simply a request? Or is there an implementation of your own that you're having problems with? Stack Overflow is a site for specific *problems*, not specific *requests*.

Comment: I want to know if somebody tried to do something like this, every place where i searched the Accordion containers where equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just specifically target the child div's and give them separate properties like this:

```
hook > div:nth-child(3){
 height: 300px !important;
}
```

div:nth-child(3) will target the last container.
!important clause will make sure to overwrite the inherited property from dojo.